# Row completar a toda a tela

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte layout:

```
-----------------------------------------------
Cabeçalho
-----------------------------------------------
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
    FORM             |        TEXTO
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
---------------------|-------------------------
Roapé
-----------------------------------------------
```

Onde cabeçalho é uma `row` individual e meu `form` e `texto` está dentro de outra `row` individual. E o rodapé é fixo:

```
<body>
    <nav class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                CABEÇALHO
            <div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5">
                FORM
            <div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-xs-7">
                TEXTO
            <div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <footer class="row">
            RODAPÉ
    </footer>
</body>
```

A dúvida é como ter as duas colunas do meio com a altura total entre o cabeçalho e o rodapé. Rodapé te um `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que isso resolve o seu problema

```
  <style>


.header{
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    height: 80px;
}

.conteudo{
    top: 80px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 160px);
    background-image: url("../img/background.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: right top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

 </style>
        <!-- Cabeçalho -->
        <div class="header">

        </div>

<!-- corpo -->
        <div class="conteudo container">
             <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5">
                FORM
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-xs-7">
                TEXTO
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<!-- footer -->
        <footer class="footer container">

        </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a porcentagem do viewport `vh` para fazer ele ocupar todo o espaço necessário.

**Exemplo:**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <header>HEADER</header>

  <section class="row">
    <section class="col-md-6 foo">FORM</section>
    <section class="col-md-6">TEXT</section>
  </section>

  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</div>

.foo {
  border-right: thick dotted black;
  height:100vh; 
}
```

Veja no [jsffidle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/kLzn461s/3/)

Referencia: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths